# "undefined symbol" during execution in C++

Tags: c++, undefined, symbols

My program compiles and links without an error. However when I start to run the program, it says

```
"undefined symbol: _ZN6Flexus11SharedTypes19FastBranchPredictor9combiningERKSsj"
```

How it is possible? If there is anything vague, it should not link the program.

DeMangeled:

```
Flexus::SharedTypes::FastBranchPredictor::combining(std::string const&, unsigned int)
```

Comment: Is this VC++ or g++, are the libraries being statically linked or dynamically linked ?

Comment: Only g++ has this problem. VC++ doesnt.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're linking to a dynamic library which doesn't contain a function you're trying to call from it. The compiler and/or linker cannot detect the error because you're linking to the library runtime

Comment: thanks for the tip. I found that I didn't include my file in the make process. In another word, In a.cpp, I defined something and in b.cpp I used that. However I forgot to include 'a' in make process. Make only process 'b'.